# How to create a list of six unit vectors in 3D?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to have a list `{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,-1}}`. How to generate it smartly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
Join[IdentityMatrix[3], -IdentityMatrix[3]]
(*  {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}  *)
```

Comment: +1: Good one! Thanks!

Comment: I like the variant `Join[#, -#] &@IdentityMatrix[3]`

Comment: @mikado Yeah, I thought of that, but too much top-row-shift typing for my podgy fingers compared to I-d--<kbd>return</kbd>... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Join@@(Permutations[#]&/@{#,-#}&@{1,0,0})
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}

Answer (score 1):

`UnitVector`:

```
Join[#, -#] &@(UnitVector[3, #] & /@ Range[3])
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}
> ```